# How to get the View Header and Footer in Custom Module?

Tags: views

I've made a custom view and display for it like this:
[image]

How do I get the Views Header (Global Summary here) ? I'm able to get the Views title  like this:

```
$views = Views::getView('items_list','page_2');
$views->setOffset($page_id);
$views->execute();
$view_results = $views->result;
print_r( $views->getTitle());exit;
```

Hope someone could help me out.

Comment: I think that you can use $view->getHandler('display_id', 'footer', 'footer_id'); and the same for the header just 'header' instead.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do. Normally you would get the header and footer in the views template: `{{ header }}` and `{{ footer }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Step1 - You will create two files header.php and footer.php.
Step2 - Create a folder "include" in your theme directory.
Step3 - Suppose that your theme directory is "abc" sites/all/themes/abc. Put header.php and footer.php file in "sites/all/themes/abc/include" theme folder.
Step3 - By using html and php you can write code in header.php and footer.php.
Step4 - Now you can include both files in page.tpl.php in header area and footer area like PHP.

```
  include_once($theme_path.'/include/header.php');  
  include_once($theme_path.'/include/footer.php');
```

hope this will help